# Python "reference trick"

Tags: python, reference, idioms

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Python:

```
a=1
b=a
b=2
assert a==2
```

than by doing this "hack":

```
a=[1]
b=a
b[0]=2
assert a[0]==2
```

Comment: Create a class with the attribute and mutate the attributes. Python variables already act like references

Comment: I'd say the idiomatic way to do that is not to do it. Why do you need to do that? Why would you want to change another variable's value?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I agree. Why would you want to do this in the first place? This screams X-Y problem to me.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I want to pass it as an argument by reference

Comment: @Akababa Python does not support call by reference semantics. No modern language does. Why don't you just try to write code that works with what the language was designed to do?

Comment: So then the answers in this question should help you find a solution: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](//stackoverflow.com/q/986006)

Comment: @Akababa:  What do you mean by pass-by-reference?  This is not sarcasm or a trick question.  Python does pass-by-assignment.  The new name in the argument list of the function or method refers to the same object as the name that was passed to the function or method.  But!  Simple assignment to a name in Python never mutates an object.  It only associates a name with an object.  So if your goal is to mutate an argument you either need to call a mutating method on that object or pass back a new object. (`b[0]=2` is a mutating method, not assignment to a name.)